# calling getWidth() on child view of custom linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I create a custom view by extending LinearLayout. At what **first** point in the lifecycle of the layout may I call `getWidth()` on a child view and get a positive value?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the activity, after onResume, and if you are in the View itself after the method "onLayout" is called...

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
}
```

OR

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Regards!